# Display value + text using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I am a total beginner. I have a form in HTML and am trying to calculate a specific value using jQuery. I want this value to be displayed in paragraph `<p id="final"></p>` under the submit button, but am actually not sure, why my code isn't working.

```
jQuery(document).on("ready", function() {
    jQuery("final").hide();         
    jQuery("#form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
        /*
            some calculations
        */
        $('#final').html($('#final').html().replace('','result + " text"'));
        jQuery("#final").show();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea, what could I be doing wrong??

Comment: What are you expecting `replace('','result + " text"')` to do?

Comment: That was a solution I found on StackOverflow, so I thought it only replaces the text inside the <p> tag and as soon as my paragraph doesn't contain any text in the first place, the first quotes are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a several issues here.

Firstly, don't mix `jQuery` and `$`. If you're using the former, it's normally to avoid jQuery's alias, `$`, from conflicting with other code that might use `$`.

Secondly, you don't actually do any calculation (from what I can see in your code), so I'm not sure what you're wanting to output. I'll assume you're going to fill that in later.

Thirdly, `jQuery('final').hide()` is missing the `#` denoting you're targeting by element ID.

Fourthly, the line

```
$('#final').html($('#final').html().replace('','result + " text"'));
```

...doesn't quite do what you think it does. For one thing, it makes no reference to your `data` variable. And running `replace()` on an empty string doesn't make much sense.

All in all I'm guessing you want something like (note also how I cache the `#final` element - that's better for perforamnce):

```
jQuery(function() { //<-- another way to write a document-ready handler
    let el = jQuery('#final');
    el.hide();         
    jQuery("#form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
        let calc = 5+2; //<-- do what you need to here
        el.html(calc).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing `result` is your variable and your above code is your current status, you should fix the html replacement to something like (depending on your acutal usecase):

```
$('#final').html(result + " text"));
```

Comment: I tried doing this way, but in the console I get this Error: ```Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function```. The other functions and the whole code works.